# Can you please remove that annoying "giphy" from the developer survey 2020 blog?

Tags: support, blog

When looking at the [blog page](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/02/05/the-2020-developer-survey-is-now-open), I see Gary Oldman (?)

[image: giphy-gary]

yelling at me.

Seriously, my motivation to participate in *your* interview to give *you* more data ... is pretty close to not existing anyway (and something tells me that many of the experienced users on this network might hold similar grudges).

The last thing you should be doing: throw animated images of angry people at me. Sure, I get it that some people might find it funny, but then: a smaller non-animated picture, maybe linking to some 5 second youtube video would achieve the same. Without reminding people about an interview Joel gave last year suggesting to bring in psychopath CEOs and such.

Comment: You're not saying it's annoying *everyone*, are you?

Comment: I am sure some people like being yelled at by Gary Oldman.

Comment: And it's fricking ***moving***, too! Even if it weren't so trashy — and it is — it's still distracting, annoying, and disrespectful. It's almost like they're deliberately priming us by making us pissed off and angry before we even go into the survey. Clever! Let us know how that works out for you, guys.

Comment: @Mast Me too. I just noticed the new Blog link here on MSE later today, and yes, that blinking moving stuff just got at me.

Comment: If I am going to be yelled at... 

Comment: maybe the survey could be improved by switching to that "Time Machine" css stylesheet  that was used for that April Fool "joke" last year. Worked great as a pain trigger to keep people away from the site for the whole day.

Comment: That's because of these Stack Exchange communications that I was looking for a [meme blocker for Google Chrome](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/28659/903)…

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

That super-nasty animated gif is now gone from [the blog post that had it](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/02/05/the-2020-developer-survey-is-now-open/).