# Can you please consider to use the word "please" more often?

Tags: discussion, blog

The "reminder" [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/02/19/new-decade-new-survey-goals-reminder-to-take-the-survey-before-it-closes-next-week) about the 2020 developer survey says:

> First and foremost, we ask that you share the survey with your networks.

and

> ... we want to learn about how they work.

Okay, I got it. You **want** something from your readers. The same users that you annoyed so much over the last months, if not years.

At least me, I would feel less irritated ([déjà vu?!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343354/can-you-please-remove-that-annoying-giphy-from-the-developer-survey-2020-blog)) if you would be using language elements that are normally used when making requests to other people when asking for something *you* want.

<sub>You know, like "please". Not in every sentence, sure. But maybe more than 0 times in a blog post that is solely a request to your readers to do something that *you* want.</sub>

--

**Edit**: the downvotes clearly indicate that people dislike the "nitpicking" on single words such as please. But note: the *underlying* point of this question was also to express my disagreement with the general tune of the survey. It turned into nitpicking, but wasn't necessarily meant as such.

The blog author assumes that is fine to put such requests to the users (like: distribute in your network), not mentioning once that some users might not be motivated to support SE Inc. activities at this point.

Comment: There are several points that the mention that they are asking, requesting, and appreciating input.  I fully believe that there are reasons to be upset at the company, however nitpicking that an article doesn't contain "please" is just a bit too much.  This article doesn't read as a demand, it reads as a request; One you are fully welcome to refuse should that _please_ you.

Comment: @RageFoxx I see that point about nitpicking. Probably I was just surprised about that chuzpa to suggest to even go and advertize *their* survey ... and well, maybe I just "okay boom'ered" myself.

Comment: I find it rude and abrupt that it doesn't begin by greeting the person, [Bonjour](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/28921/5753), before getting down to business, but I know that's culture-specific!

Comment: When I was a kid, "there's a word missing" was something that certain adults (teachers, shopkeepers, etc) used to say if you hadn't said "please". The missing word was, of course, "please". 40 years later saying "please" no longer sounds polite, it actually sounds the exact opposite, it sounds like you're talking down to the person you're addressing. Maybe put this one down to cultural differences, but I'd have more respect for a request if it didn't have a "please" in it.

Comment: @MaximusMinimus That is one way to look at it. The other is way is: readers here complain about my narrow view on "that one word". Yet I get the feeling that the readers also look my posting with a very narrow view. Sure, my focus on "please" was a bad starting point, but then: do you think many users here are *happy* about how SE Inc. put up that request, especially with parts "and yeah, share this with all your network"?! Not mentioning once that maybe some users feel reluctant about participation.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

That request was adding insult to injury, no question. The idea that the very company that has been treating us like dirt for the past year now expects us to start spamming our friends for them is beyond the pale!

However, "we ask that" is perfectly courteous and polite phrasing. Saying "We ask that you do this" is actually *more* polite than "Please do this". You could, perhaps, go as far as "We ask that you please do this" but that's starting to get ridiculous.

So, while I completely share your offense at the request and, most importantly, at the level of tone-deafness and utter ignorance of the company's relationship with the community that the request demonstrates, I cannot find fault with the language as such.

Comment: Probably true. Still ...

Comment: It may be that GhostCat is not native English speaker and interpreted "ask somebody to do something" as a demand and sign of impoliteness.